# How to read a Map stored in s3 as a file as a json in spark?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have a map stored in S3 without schema, so it's like {id1: val1, id2: val2} and want to convert it to a json dataframe with rows like: [{id:id1, value: val1}, {id:id2, value: val2}]

Reading it directly as spark.read.json("s3://...") gives a single row with all the id's as columns and the values' as value.

Answer (score 2):

One relatively simple solution if you have access to input file is to modify file to look like this

```
{ "map" :{"id1": "val1", "id2": "val2"}}
```

and then read it like this

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = new StructType().add("map", MapType(StringType, StringType))

val df = spark.read.schema(schema).json("s3://...")
df.select(explode($"map") as (Seq("id","value")))
```

Other solution is to read it as line of text and then convert it with help of some Json processing library (like Jackson)

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val df = spark.read.text("s3://...")

val mapper = new ObjectMapper()

case class idValue(id: String, value: String)

df.flatMap { row =>
     val jsonContent = mapper.readTree(new String(row.getString(0))).asInstanceOf[ObjectNode]
     jsonContent.fields().asScala.toList.map { map =>
       idValue(map.getKey, map.getValue.asText)
     }
   }
```

Comment: There should be a way to do it in spark only without modifying the input other than text parsing

Comment: Since I was creating the data in S3, I modified the hash map to be an ArrayList of HashMaps, therefore now you can read it natively using spark.read.json and it picks up the keys as colNames and values as values.

Comment: So the data in S3 looks like: 
`[{id:id1, value: val1}, {id:id2, value: val2}] and
df.printSchema will give  
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)`